# Accessing FAKE build target name inside target function

Tags: f#-fake

I have two targets (among others) in my build script - BuildApp and Deploy. Deploy target function needs to get a package, which is generated by BuildApp target. However, BuildApp target should not always create this package, since it is only required if the final target is Deploy.

My question is if there any way to detect, what is the final specified target (or all targets list) for the current run, inside the target function, so in BuildApp I can have a condition to create a package only if final target (or target list) contains "Deploy" string.

Comment: This seems hacky. Can you restructure your build to avoid this lookup? Perhaps add another target "GenerateDeployPackage" and make the "Deploy" target dependent on it?

Comment: I am using OctoPack and it just accepts msbuild parameters "RunOctoPack=true", so it is actually a rebuild

Comment: So make two different targets, "RegularBuild" and "BuildWithOctoPack", and make "Deploy" dependent on the latter.

Comment: Not sure I understand you.

I have this build order
"Clean"
  ==> "BuildApp"
  ==> "Test"
  ==> "Pack"
  ==> "Push"
  ==> "Deploy"

Where the new BuildWithOctoPack would fit here? Or you suggest building twice, then it will double the build time.

Comment: Have non-linear dependency chain. You would have one `"Clean" ==> "BuildApp" ==> "Test"`, and then also `"Clean" ==> "BuildWithOctoPack" ==> "Test" ==> "Pack" ==> "Push" ==> "Deploy"`.

Comment: OK, sounds good, thanks. I, however, found out that OctoPack uses nuget install scripts and this doesn't work with paket, which I use, so I have to find another solution now :)